# Does long time IO operation in Electron main process block the UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I know that CPU intensive work in main process will block the UI process. I have another question, does long time IO operation in main process block the UI. 
Recently, I use electron to develop a desktop application of file management.

### Step 1:

My UI process use asynchronous IPC (provided by Electron) to tell the main-process to fetch data of file list from network, (only fetch meta data of file, not contain file content)

### Step 2:

Main-process fetch data of file list from network and then store the file list into sqlite(I use TypeORM ), and then select parts of the file list from sqlite, and response them back to UI-process

---

Sometimes the step2 costs tens of seconds (for example, I fetch 10000 items of file data from network ), and my UI will be slowed down.

So, I have two question: 
+ Does long time IO operation in main process block the UI ?
+ What's the best way to do IO operation(database or local file) in electron applcation ?

Comment: Moving big chunks of data between the main and the renderer process can slow down Electron. How do you "response them back to UI-process"?

Comment: i use ipc async, and just transform pure json string @PelayoMéndez

Now i try to move my logic of data manager from main process  to another process

Comment: Yes try to do that. It's not a good idea to block the main process. To make the operation truly async it should run on it's on process. Check this article contains a great explanation about this issue within a real world example: https://medium.com/actualbudget/the-horror-of-blocking-electrons-main-process-351bf11a763c

Answer (score 0):

Potentially, I/O can block your application. Node offers blocking and non-blocking I/O operations. You'll want to use the non-blocking variants.

The Node docs have a section on [blocking vs non-blocking I/O](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking/#comparing-code). Two code samples from that page, one blocking, one non-blocking:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('/file.md'); // blocks here until file is read
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/file.md', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Note that even if OP uses blocking I/O operations in Node it still shouldn't block the electron UI thread.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I use async IO operation, but i dont know why my ui thread is still be slowed down when the IO operation costs tens of seconds.
And my sqlite operation is also in the async way as it is mentioned here https://typeorm.io/#/

Comment: I recommend you read the devtools docs and use the profiler, it's a godsend and it can tell you exactly where your program is spending its time :]

Answer (score -1):

The second question ("what's the best way?") is opinionated and off-topic so I'll focus on the first:

> Does long time IO operation in main process block the UI ?

No it does not. I/O in electron happens either from the Chromium side or the Node.js side - in both cases JavaScript's I/O execution model uses an event loop. The action is queued and then performed either on a threadpool in the background (like dns queries for example) or using native operating system async non-blocking I/O facilities (like socket writes).

The one caveat is the browsers do offer some (older) APIs that are blocking (like a synchronous XMLHttpRequest), but you are likely not using those.

For more details see [our event loop and timers tutorial](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).